# Uploading and accessing files in Azure without using the Data Storage

Tags: php, asp.net, azure

If using Windows Azure and an ASP.NET web site with PHP script to upload files, can I access those files from the server or must I use the Data Storage facilities?

i.e. I'd like to reference the files directly from html\server... etc. I think I probably should be able to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you hosting your ASP.NET website. If it's hosted in a Web Role, then you won't have access to a persistent "standard" file system for that role. (especially if you've scaled over multiple instances).

Have a look at the following tutorial on using blob storage from PHP. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/

You can use the blob storage quite easily to access them with standard HTTP links from your ASP.NET site. i.e.

[http://**your-storage-account**.blob.core.windows.net/**your-container**/file.txt](http://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/your-container/file.txt)

Comment: Ah, yes it's a basic web role. Thanks very much for the PHP tutorial link, that looks like it'll be quite useful.